# Knockout Select2 set initial value by object

Tags: html, select, knockout.js, jquery-select2, dropdown

I have a Knockout.js web application where I have a select2 dropdown. I want to bind both the id and text values to a variable instead of just the id. Here's my data:

```
var cars = [{id: 1, name: 'Honda'}, {id: 2, name: 'Toyota'}, {id: 3, name: 'Dodge'}];
var selectedCar = ko.observable();
```

Here's my html:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedCar, optionsCaption: 'Select', optionsText: 'name', options: cars"></select>
```

So now, whenever I select something in the dropdown my variable contains the entire object like so:

```
selectedCar = {id: 1, name: 'Honda'};
```

The only problem occurs when you load the page and want the dropdown to be set to a specific value. Even though before rendering the html the `selectedCar` variable is set to `{id: 1, name: 'Honda'}` when the page renders the dropdown is not set to anything, it just is set to the placeholder 'Select'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Great question, learnt something new by answering this

Comment: hi.. any thoughts on the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind both the id and text value to a variable, you need to use the `optionsValue` binding and bind the entire context to it (`$data`);

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedCar, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select', 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   options: cars, 
                   optionsValue: $data"></select>
```

Normally we would specify the id or whatever to get an initial value selected. So it would make sense like in your question to supply the entire object `{id: 1, name: 'Honda'}` as the initial value to `selectedCar` if wet set `optionsValue: $data` and not `$optionsValue: 'id'`.

(**IMPORTANT**) But turns out this doesn't work, because we're creating a new object and so Knockout's equality test will fail when it compares the objects of `cars` with the object inside `selectedCar`. The correct way to set the initial value is `cars[0]`.

---

I'm sure this is a typo, but I'll specify anyway: when you create any variable that needs to be accessed by the HTML you need to bind it to `this`, which would be a reference to the viewModel.

```
this.cars = [{id: 1, name: 'Honda'}, {id: 2, name: 'Toyota'}, {id: 3, name: 'Dodge'}];
this.selectedCar = ko.observable();
```

Let's test all this with a fiddle:

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.cars = [{id: 1, name: 'Honda'}, {id: 2, name: 'Toyota'}, {id: 3, name: 'Dodge'}];
  self.selectedCar = ko.observable(self.cars[0]);
  

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="value: selectedCar, optionsCaption: 'Select', optionsText: 'name', optionsValue:$data, options: cars"></select>

<!-- to verify that we are getting the entire object -->
<p data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedCar)"></p>
```

Comment: Setting the `optionsValue` in that way is unnecessary, the selected item is implied as the value.

Comment: Yes, but how would you set an initial value and also meet OP's requirement of binding both id and text to 'selectedCar'? I think at that point optionsValue becomes necessary.

Comment: The setting `optionsValue: $data` will not do what you're thinking. `$data` in that context is actually the view model which is not a valid value for that property. So in effect, it's using the default behavior (the selected item is set to the value). You have pointed out correctly however that the initial value for `selectedCar` is set correctly by accessing the actual instance in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of a select box will become the object that corresponds to the selected item or the property set in the `optionsValue` parameter. So in the case of objects, the selected value you set must be the same instance that exists in the array. Having a different instance of an object happens to be structurally equivalent is not enough.

For situations like this, I find it easier to bind the value of the select box to a unique id for the object instead. Then you could map out that id to the actual instance that you want through a computed value.

```js
function ViewModel(data) {
    this.cars = data.cars;
    this.selectedCarId = ko.observable(data.selectedCarId);
    this.selectedCar = ko.computed(() => {
        let selectedCarId = this.selectedCarId();
        return this.cars.find(c => c.id === selectedCarId);
    });
}

let model = {
    cars: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Honda' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Toyota' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Dodge' }
    ],
    selectedCarId: 2
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(model), document.getElementById('content'));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <select data-bind="value: selectedCarId,
                     optionsCaption: 'Select',
                     optionsText: 'name',
                     optionsValue: 'id',
                     options: cars">
  </select>
  <p>selectedCarId: <span data-bind="text: selectedCarId"></span></p>
  <p>selectedCar: <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedCar)"></span></p>
  
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

If you'd rather not use a separate computed property, you would still need to pass in an index, but the value you set, must be obtained from the array.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    this.cars = data.cars;
    this.selectedCar = ko.observable(
        data.cars.find(c => c.id === data.selectedCarId)
    );
}
```